# How to trigger the display message on the right way

Tags: angular, typescript

I dont really know what im missing. The communication beetwen components works, i use input decorator to pass data from parent to child. However, the message doesnt display when the button is clicked. It displays when the prompt is in the input box and i click outside the box. I would need to know what's wrong cos mi idea is that the message displays when the button is clicked without touching the box.

// forgot-password.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from '../../services/login.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-forgot-password',
  templateUrl: './forgot-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forgot-password.component.less']
})
export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  empty: boolean;
  processStarted: boolean;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    });
  }

  recoverLostPassword() {
    if (this.email.value !== null && this.email.valid) {
      this.loginService.recoverLostPassword(this.email.value).subscribe(() => {
        this.processStarted = true;
      });
    }
    if (this.email.value === null) {
      this.empty = true; // la utilizo para hacer el binding en el child component
    }
  }

  get email() { return this.form.get('email'); }

}
```

// forgot-password.component.html

```
<section>

  <div class="form" [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="email" type="email" pInputText placeholder="Email">
    <lp-form-field-errors [serverErrors]="serverErrors" bindToErrorsKey="email" [control]="email" [empty]="empty"></lp-form-field-errors>
    <button pButton label="Recuperar contraseña" [disabled]="processStarted" (click)="recoverLostPassword()"></button>
    <div>
      Volver al <a [routerLink]="['login']">inicio de sesión</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="processStarted">
    <p>
      El proceso de recuperación de contraseña fue iniciado con éxito.
    </p>
    <p>
      Le hemos enviado un correo con las instrucciones para poder reestablecer la clave de su cuenta, por favor
      revise su casilla.
    </p>
  </div>

</section>
```

// form-field-errors.component.ts

```
import { ValidationResult } from '../../../model/core/validation-result';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'lp-form-field-errors',
  templateUrl: './form-field-errors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-field-errors.component.css']
})
export class FormFieldErrorsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  empty: boolean;
  @Input()
  serverErrors: ValidationResult;
  @Input()
  patternErrorMessage: string;
  @Input()
  bindToErrorsKey: string;
  @Input()
  control: AbstractControl;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

// form-field-errors.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched)"
     class="form-field-errors-container">

  <div *ngIf="control.errors?.required || empty">
    Este campo es requerido
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="control.errors?.email">
    Ingrese un email válido
  </div>

</div>

<div *ngIf="serverErrors" class="form-field-errors-container">
  <div *ngFor="let err of serverErrors.fieldErrors[bindToErrorsKey]">
    {{err}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to create a demo to show the problem.